# Loop through groups of spans in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<td style="display:none;">
                        <span class="runId">4</span><span class="processName">Get End-Of-Day Reuters Feed Rates</span>
                        <span class="runId">130</span><span class="processName">Get End-Of-Day Bloomberg Feed Rates</span>
                        <span class="runId">133</span><span class="processName">CapVolsCalibration AllCurrencies EOD</span>
                        <span class="runId">228</span><span class="processName">GBP Basis Adjustment</span>
                </td>
```

Hey guys, how would I loop through this `<td>` in JQuery and for each group of two `span` elements, get the `text()` of the `runId` and the `processName` elements.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functional programming to the rescue:

```
var data = $td.children('span.runId').map(function() {
   return {runId: $(this).text(), processName: $(this).next().text()};
}).get();
```

Structure the data how ever you want to.

Comment: Depending on what he needs to do with this data, this might be a little more complex than needed.  Nonetheless, well done.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("span.runId").each(function(){
    var runId = $(this).text(),
        processname = $(this).next("span.processName").text();
});
```

Comment: I'll whip up a better one momentarily ;)

Comment: I went a different route altogether.  Suggested html structure change.

Comment: +1 for effort :) and yes i can see what you mean it is more minimalistic and probably something i would do mysely and just use attr('id') to fetch the ID ofc. nice one :)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I would suggest that if they have that type of correlation that they are wrapped together in another tag, or better yet combined as they are not even displayed.  This, of course, does not apply to parsing code you do not have write/modify access to.

Suggested html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="display:none;">
            <span data-runid='4' class="processName">Get End-Of-Day Reuters Feed Rates</span>
            <span data-runid='130' class="processName">Get End-Of-Day Bloomberg Feed Rates</span>
            <span data-runid='133' class="processName">CapVolsCalibration AllCurrencies EOD</span>
            <span data-runid='228' class="processName">GBP Basis Adjustment</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$("td span.processName").each(function() {
    var runid, processName, $this = $(this);
    runid = $this.data('runid');
    processName = $this.text();
});
```

I'm not exactly sure what your needs are, but I'd even get rid of the class `processName` as well.  Since the data isn't displayed, it's not really needed at this level assuming you don't need to access this for other purposes.  This minimizes down to:

html:

```
<table id='someId'>
    <tr>
        <td style="display:none;">
            <span data-runid='4'>Get End-Of-Day Reuters Feed Rates</span>
            <span data-runid='130'>Get End-Of-Day Bloomberg Feed Rates</span>
            <span data-runid='133'>CapVolsCalibration AllCurrencies EOD</span>
            <span data-runid='228'>GBP Basis Adjustment</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#someId").find('td span').each(function() {
    var runid, processName, $this = $(this);
    runId = $this.data('runid');
    processName = $this.text();
});
```

Technically, you can't have a `span` outside of a `td` in a `table`, so it could be reduced further:

```
$("#someId").find('span').each(function() {
    var runid, processName, $this = $(this);
    runId = $this.data('runid');
    processName = $this.text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So many ways to do things with jQuery:

```
$('td > span:nth-child(2n-1)').text(function(i,txt) { 
    alert(txt + $(this).next().text());
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/vqs38/