# How add items from html <span> to an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want make an array that contains all of the text from the span elements that have the `shopping-item` class. My attempts to do so have resulted in either the array containing `[Object object]` or `[object HTMLSpanElement]`. I just want the text which that span element contains, nothing else.

I've tried [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427490/loop-through-groups-of-spans-in-jquery) and others from Stack. I've tried using the `map` method, currently I tried using the `toArray` method in an effort to view what was being stored inside of the array. Some of the code I have tried is below.

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>

  <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
    <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
    <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
    <button type="submit">Add item</button>
  </form>

  <ul class="shopping-list">
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">oranges</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item shopping-item__checked">milk</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
      </div>
    </li>
```

```js
//Here are some of my attempts for context.

//1ST attempt
const list = $('span.shopping-item').toArray();
for (prop in list) {
  alert(`${prop} = ${list[prop]}`);
}

//another attempt
let data = $('li').children('span.shopping-item').map(function() {
  return {
    item: $(this).text()
  };
}).get();

//another attempt
const list = ('ul.shopping-list').children('span.shopping-item').map(function(item) {
  return item;
});
```

I expect an output of:

```
['apples', 'oranges', 'milk', 'bread']
```

When I display the list with `alert()`. However, this is what I get `[Object object]`, `[object HTMLSpanElement]` or sometimes just a whole list full of `[Object object]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is almost there, you just need to return the `text()` directly; there's no need to place it in the property of an object:

```js
let data = $('li').children('span.shopping-item').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>

  <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
    <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
    <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
    <button type="submit">Add item</button>
  </form>

  <ul class="shopping-list">
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">oranges</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item shopping-item__checked">milk</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pointy - Do we really need "$('li').children('span.shopping-item')" as this will make the selection very closed-ended. Hence let's keep it as "$('.shopping-item')"

Comment: @RonitMukherjee I assume the OP left that restriction in for a reason.

Comment: Closed-ended selectors are not good as they are very dependent on HTML structure, change in structure will stop the code.

Comment: In some cases they are required. We don't know enough about the use case here to advise either way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Vanilla JavaScript solution, which makes use of the [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method:

```js
const list = [];
document.querySelectorAll('.shopping-item').forEach(item => list.push(item.innerText));

console.log(list); // ['apples', 'oranges', 'milk']
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>

  <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
    <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
    <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
    <button type="submit">Add item</button>
  </form>

  <ul class="shopping-list">
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
          <span class="button-label">check</span>
        </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
          <span class="button-label">delete</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">oranges</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
          <span class="button-label">check</span>
        </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
          <span class="button-label">delete</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item shopping-item__checked">milk</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
          <span class="button-label">check</span>
        </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
          <span class="button-label">delete</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short solution

```js
let spanArray = [];
document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(element => {
    spanArray.push(element.innerHTML);
});

console.log(spanArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var lists = $('.shopping-item');
var list_array=[];
lists.each(function(){
    list_array.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(list_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let allItem = [];
$('li span.shopping-item').each(function(){
    allItem.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(allItem);
```

Comment: Please don't just post some snippet of code as an answer. At least demonstrate how it solves the problem in the answer itself.